# Validar Login PHP PDO MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Olá estou começando com php já engajado no mundo do PDO e estou com uma **duvida no meu código**

> quero verificar se o login existe e é o mesmo que foi inserido, se
>   for retorna "login existente" se não "não existe login"

Mais toda hora está retornando falso.

Exemplo a baixo

```
require_once("conexao.php");
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT nome, senha FROM login where nome=? and senha=?");
$resultado = $conn->prepare($sql);
$resultado->bindParam(1, $_POST['nome']);
$resultado->bindParam(2, $_POST['senha']);
$resultado->execute();
if($resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) == true):
echo"existe login";

else:
echo"não existe login";
endif;
```

> Alguém pode me ajudar, seguindo claro a regra do PDO e me informa
>   alguns exemplos com artigos argumentando sobre o assunto.

Answer (score -1):

Talvez possa ser ser por falta do **beginTransaction()** e do **commit()**. Caso ainda não for, coloca um TryCatch e vê se exibe algum erro.

```
require_once("conexao.php");
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT nome, senha FROM login where nome=? and senha=?");
$conn->beginTransaction();
$resultado = $conn->prepare($sql);
$resultado->bindParam(1, $_POST['nome']);
$resultado->bindParam(2, $_POST['senha']);
$resultado->execute();
$con->commit();
if($resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) == true):
echo"existe login";

else:
$conn->rollBack();
echo"não existe login";
endif;
```

Comment: beginTransaction()  poderia me explica um pouco mais sobre esse method?

Comment: Ele "desativa o modo de confirmação automática. Enquanto o modo de confirmação automática estiver desativado, as alterações feitas no banco de dados por meio da instância do objeto PDO não serão confirmadas até que você finalize a transação chamando o **Commit()**" (Documentação do PDO), basicamente ele executa a query e fica esperando o Commit para aplicar de vez a query no banco. Eu não sei se ela faz alguma diferença em relação a um **Select**, mas segundo meu Professor é sempre interessante colocar em qualquer tipo de Query.